# User can't git submodule update, but they can pull from all submodules independantly

Tags: git, permissions, git-submodules

I have a new team member who gets a Permission Error when trying to perform their initial `git submodule update`:

```
[mrTeamMember@desktop application]$ git submodule update
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/mrTeamMember/work/application/subMod/.git/
mrTeamMember@server.example.com's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

If, however, they simply `git pull` from the submodules' repositories directly, they get no error!

How can this be?

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check recent history as the url in the .gitmodules file has probably changed. Given that you did not do a `git submodule init` the submodule repo still contains a working url.